# is there import_id parameter for wp_insert_term to create custom id for category

Tags: wordpress

is there option to create category with custom id like custom post id is created using parameter import_id ?

`$post = array(
'post_title'=>'whatever',
'post_content'=>'whatever',
'import_id'=>123
);
wp_insert_post($post);`

what i want to do is create custom post type ( will import data from table which have category id attached ) using wp_insert_post

so i want to create categories with custom id that are attached to products table

right now i'm using custom field added to categories as OLD_CATEGORY_ID and get posts against this custom field id

*categories are also imported from custom table

or is there another better way ?

or this is the ONLY way ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I use post meta. Unfortunately wp_insert_post() is for the posts table only. Though if you want there is 1 filter 'update_post_metadata' in which you could deal with a new column there. But post_meta is included in WP_QUERY so its actually a more workable solution if you need to be able to use the old ids.

```
if($post) 
update_post_meta($post,'_import_id', $importid);
```